# Realms blocked by Internet Blocker (Integard)

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues, minecraft-java-edition-realms

My brother and I have been trying to play Minecraft together for a long time, but have never been successful. We have always run into some error message, no matter what we tried. I have recently purchased a PC that does not yet have our family blocker software (Integard) installed on it. On it, I found that I was finally able to connect to Minecraft Realms. However, my brother still cannot.

Because of this, we believe that the problem lies with Integard, the Internet Blocker application installed on our computers (except mine). To prove this, our parents temporarily disabled Integard, and he was able to successfully connect to the Realm. However, when the blocker was renabled, he again hit the Connection Blocked error message.

Does anyone know how to allow Minecraft through Integard, or a similar blocker? There is a list of allowed programs, which Minecraft is now on, but I'm not sure if this will work. Let me know if anyone has run into this before, or knows how to fix it. Also, is there a port number that Minecraft Realms runs through? If so, I could probably let it through. Thanks!

Comment: You'll need to add a rule to allow Minecraft through the Firewall. I'm not sure that this is on-topic for Arqade however...

Comment: You'll likely have more luck with this if you ask on [Super User](http://superuser.com/)

Comment: @Ben The reason I posted here is that I wasn't sure if there was a Realm's setting I could adjust (ie port number) and thought that some people who have played it may relate to this issue... Also, I have already tried disabling the Firewall completely, and it did not fix the game.

Comment: Sorry, when I say "firewall" I am referring to your internet security program - "Integard". There is likely a way for you to allow Minecraft through a port in Integard, similar to how you might allow a program through a firewall. @Ezekiel's answer provides some insight, but as  I said, you'll likely have more luck over on Super User.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about disabling a third party program, not a game configuration or gameplay issue.

Comment: @Frank Just got it figured out, and you're right, it's actually not about Realms. But for those who find this question, I'll post an answer anyway.

Comment: I'm reopening this question because the port information is very useful for future visitors, and you're not really specifically asking about your software, but about any general firewall software. While we can't help configure specific softwares, this question and answer do have useful information.

Comment: @Frank was right. This question is purely about configuration of a third-party program, and has nothing to do with gaming. It should be closed as off-topic.

Comment: Alternatively, it can be locked by an admin to keep the information intact.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because is a problem with 3rd party software and not the game itself.

Comment: I'm voting to leave this question open because it is a question centered around getting a game to work, is clear and concise, and has information valuable to fellow gamers. Just because the answer involves a third-party tool does not automatically make the question off-topic.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I finally figured out what the problem was just now. It turns out that the Realms are allowed through Windows Firewall with no problem; rather, the problem came from Integard's Firewall. To fix this, I have to allow port 25565 through the Integard Firewall, and everything seems to be working.

Answer (score 0):

I personally have not used Integard and cannot find resources for it online. However I can provide details for how Minecraft Realms connects and where the problem might be.

Based on the screenshots I can find, you should be able to configure Integard to not block Minecraft. You may, however, run into issues specifically that Minecraft is run under the `java` process. I would recommend trying to configure Minecraft to have no internet restrictions.

---edit---

Here is a screenshot showing how I configure my Firewall to not block Minecraft. I don't know wether this will help but I figured I'd attach it.

[image: Little Snitch Firewall]

Comment: Yeah, finding resources about Integard is impossible...I wonder if they no longer provide support? I have already tried fully disabling the Firewall, but to no avail. However, when Integard is disabled he is able to connect... Oh well, I'll keep trying :)

Comment: Thanks Ezekiel. Read my update (answer) for details of what happened. It was a firewall issue, just not Windows :)